# NSSortDescriptor and to-many relationships

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm working with an `NSFetchedResultsController` to show data in a UITableView. I have a to many relationship which looks something like this:

`Article` `---->>` `Tag`

One article has many tags.

I'd like to order them so that all tags that have the title "Banana" come before those that have the tag "Orange" which in turn are before those tagged "Apple" etc. The title is an attribute on the tag.

I was considering using an NSSortDescriptor. I've implemented a method called "position" in my Tag NSManagedObject subclass. This method returns an NSInteger which describes the order of the tags.

The issue is that NSSortDescriptor does not support to-many relationships. (The console reads: "to-many key not allowed here".) Here's what I tried:

```
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"tags.tagText" ascending:YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {

    if ([obj1 position] > [obj2 position]) { 
         return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
        }
    if ([obj1 position] < [obj2 position]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
         }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Any idea what the answer is? How can I do a sort based on an arbitrary value of a property of another entity which is linked via a to-many relationship?

**EDIT:**

I'm now wondering if I can use a method in my Article class to help with the sorting. I would do something like this:

```
 - (NSInteger)position{

NSInteger aPosition = 100;

for (Tag *aTag in self.tags) {
    if (position > [aTag position]) {
        aPosition = [aTag position];
    }
}

return aPosition;
}
```

Is there a way to have my NSSortDescriptor call this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the `Tag` has a `title` attribute and you want to display a tableview full of articles that are broken into sections where the section is the title from the tag?

Assuming that is correct the short answer is you can't.  The sort doesn't make sense because an `Article` can and will be in more than one position in the sort.  If an article has the tag Apple and Orange, where should it be placed?

Comment: It's in the Tag. The tags are a to-many relationship on the article.

Comment: In the case of a dual tag, Why can't I just be consistent with following either the first or the last tag? There are other tags which don't effect sort order, which does theoretically allow for two relevant tags, but again, what's wrong with doing so as long I'm being consistent?

Comment: Which one is the first tag? Which one is the last tag? Relationships are not ordered by default. So you are wanting to order by tag.order and then by first tag?  That is beyond what the `NSFetchRequest` can do on its own.  However you could build your own version of the `NSFetchedResultsController` that does this fairly complex sort. You could base it on the work I did in the [ZSContextWatcher](https://github.com/ZarraStudios/ZDS_Shared).

Comment: I just had a thought - Can I add a method to my Article class to get the "highest sort index" of its given tags and just use that to determine the sort order?

Comment: Yes but that cannot be performed during the fetch as the method will only be available as a sort option once the data is loaded into memory.  This is part of why I suggested building your own `NSFetchResultsController` so that you could perform a custom sort after the data is loaded.

Comment: Am I supposed to just subclass NSFetchedResultsController and add my sort to it, or is there more to it?

Comment: There is more to it.  I suggest click on the link I added above for the ZSContextWatcher and look at the source code for that example.  It is not a drop in solution for your needs but it gets you most of the way there.

Comment: I spent some time (although obviously not enough of it) looking at your code. I tried to write my own subclass of NSFetchedResultsController which failed dismally. Instead, I've reassigned myself to adding a property to the managed object, which is calculated at "save time", instead of runtime, which adds the benefit of faster sorting, since Core Data uses a standard NSSortDescriptor on a numeric property and the calculations have all been done previously. Thank you for all of your help.